# Setting MTU in NIC with powershell

Tags: powershell, nic, mtu

need help

I’m facing problem with the below script that show several steps:

1. print parameters from NIC before change
2. change MTU 8000
3. print parameters from NIC after change

commands:

- Get-NetIPInterface | where {($_.interfacealias -eq  "Delivery" )} |  select NlMtu, interfacealias | ft -a
- echo "About to change the MTU"
- Get-NetIPInterface | where {($_.interfacealias -eq  "Delivery" )} | Set-NetIPInterface -NlMtuBytes 8000
- Get-NetIPInterface | where {($_.interfacealias -eq  "Delivery" )} |  select NlMtu, interfacealias | ft -a

here is shown that the MTU was changed
but run this line, show that the MTU is NOT changed

$adaptrs = Get-NetAdapter | where {$_.MtuSize -gt 1500} | select Name, MacAddress, MtuSize | ft -a foreach ($tadaptr in $adaptrs) {
echo $tadaptr }

the output is:

NlMtu interfacealias

---

9000 Delivery

About to change the MTU

NlMtu interfacealias

---

8000 Delivery

Second print :

Name     MacAddress        MtuSize

---

Delivery 00-50-56-A4-6F-15    9000

**how can I make sure witch one is affacting the MTU and where from the differences?**